# How can I get value of itemLabel form JSP using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can I get value of itemLabel form JSP using javascript?

```
 <form:radiobutton path="chosenInstitution" id="institution" itemLabel="${institution.name}" itemValue="${institution.id}"></form:radiobutton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method to get value of `itemValue` like below :

```js
//getting attribute value
var itemValue = document.getElementById("institution").getAttribute("itemValue");
//printing
console.log("itemValue=" + itemValue);
```

```html
<form:radiobutton path="chosenInstitution" id="institution" itemLabel="${institution.name}" itemValue="${institution.id}"></form:radiobutton>
```